# Relation of Bluetooth BD_ADDR and AccessAddress in BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am newer for BLE and BT, it confused me with 6 octets BD_ADDR in BT and 4 octets "Access Address" in BLE. what is different or purpose?

I can capture BT HCI on Linux wirewhark
I use wireshark to capture BLE's "Access Address"?

Regards
Robber

Comment: Here are one of answer for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160068/what-is-the-purpose-of-access-address-in-ble

Comment: Yes that thread answers what the Access Address is. BD_ADDR has no relationship at all to Access Address. The BD_ADDR is used to identify a Bluetooth device. The Access Address is just used to identify a single connection (or the fact that a packet is an advertising packet) in the air space.