# Why the Advertising Pakets of BLE has fix pattern Access address (0x8E89BED6)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

In reference to this [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160068/what-is-the-purpose-of-access-address-in-ble), the purpose of Access address in Data Packet is clear.

But can anyone please explain why in Bluetooth Low Energy specification the Advertising Packet has the Access address fixed to 0x8E89BED6?

In general discussion it is many times said that- the packet is Advertising Packet is understood due to this fix pattern. This answer wont seems logical as setting a dedicated single bit somewhere in packet would have help to recognize the same, why 4 byte data has been used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a "simple" address like 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x55555555 instead is a bad idea because the radio might see such data on the air without no one sending any advertising packet, due to background noise or similar. By having a more "random" address like 0x8E89BED6 it is extremely unlikely that invalid noise could be treated as an advertising packet.